Cannot expand a tuple pair in lockstep for a function call in index_sequence context
The question is simple (but not so the solution I guess...).
I want to apply a function to index 0 of n tuples with args, later to index 1
of tuple the same tuples with args... and so on.
Given this:

template <auto Func, class... Tuples, class... Fargs, std::size_t... Is>
auto applyInLockStep(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                     Tuples &&... tups,
                     Fargs &&...args) {
  return (Func(std::get<Is>(tups), std::forward<Fargs>(args)...), ...);
}

And assuming this is the call:
using Tup = std::tuple<float, float, float>;
Tup t1, t2;

constexpr auto f = [&]<class T1E, class T2E>(T1E && t1E,
                                   T2E && t2E,
                                   float t) {
   return myf(std::forward<T1E>(t1E), std::forward<T2E>(t2E), t);
};

applyInLockStep<f>(make_index_sequence<tuple_size_v<Tup1>>{}, t1, t2, 1.0f);

I want this expansion:
Func(std::get<0>(tup0), std::get<0>(tup1), 1.0f), 
Func(std::get<1>(tup0), std::get<1>(tup1), 1.0f), 
...

The problem is in this expression, in std::get<Is>(tups) concretely:
Func(std::get<Is>(tups), std::forward<Fargs>(args)...), ...)

I want to expand tups for the same index, but not Is, but if I do this it will only expand tups inside std::get<0>(tup1, tup2), which I do not want:
Func(std::get<Is>(tups...), std::forward<Fargs>(args)...), ...)

And if I do this:
Func(std::get<Is>(tups)..., std::forward<Fargs>(args)...), ...)

it will expand tups and Is..., but I do not want Is to be expanded.
Not sure if it is doable or not and how.

You give a very concrete code example. However, the desired expansion contains .... This makes it fuzzy what you actually want. Please show the exact expansion result. Also, choose an example where the Is and the tups are not the same length if your specification allows this case. On top of that, a tuple that has all equal types doesn't look like tuple is the right choice; it looks more like array.

The compiler cannot tell where the pack tups ends and where args starts in deduction, tups will hence always be deduced to an empty parameter pack. Your function signature simply doesn't work. I can write an answer to reach your expected expansion if you can remove args. Your question should not be tagged [tag:c++17] because you used templated lambda, which does not exist before [tag:c++20].

@WeijunZhou "Your question should not be tagged c++17 because you used templated lambda"  <- true sorry for that. It is c++14 for generic but not with explicit template parameters.

At first, in
// ..
auto applyInLockStep(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                     Tuples &&... tups,
                     Fargs &&...args)

FArgs is non-deducible, Tuples would deduce all, so FArgs would be an empty pack.
I will bypass by grouping tups inside another std::tuple
// ..
auto applyInLockStep(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                     std::tuple<Tuples...> tups,
                     Fargs &&...args)

then, you might create sub-function to allow variadic expansion in the direction you want:
template <auto Func,
          class... Tuples,
          class... Fargs,
          std::size_t I>
auto applyInLockStep(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>,
                     std::tuple<Tuples...> tups,
                     Fargs &&...args)
{
    return std::apply([&](auto&&... tup) {
         return Func(std::get<I>(tup)..., std::forward<Fargs>(args)...);
    }, tups);
}

template <auto Func,
          class... Tuples,
          class... Fargs,
          std::size_t... Is>
auto applyInLockStep(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                     std::tuple<Tuples...> tups,
                     Fargs &&...args)
{
    return (applyInLockStep<Func>(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{},
                                  std::forward<std::tuple<Tuples...>>(tups),
                                  std::forward<Fargs>(args)...),
            ...);
}

Demo

True, I did notice when I took a closer look about non-deducibility :) Let me come back to your solution by this evening (Asia/HCMC time).
